# error "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument

Tags: docker

When I am trying to add --no-cache to docker build, I get error  "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument?

```
docker build --no-cache -f dockerfiles/Dockerfile.python --build-arg TFLITE=notflite --build-arg OPENVINO=openvino VARIANT=cpu --target pyrelease --tag python-release-docker-cpu .
```

Comment: You're missing a `--build-arg` option before `VARIANT=cpu`.

Answer (score 0):

As David mentioned, I had missed one --build-arg before VARIANT=cpu